# accepts null values in unique columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
----------------------------------------
ID | company_id | barcode | product_name
----------------------------------------
```

I want to make a unique constraint for company and barcode column so no same `company_id` can have the same barcode number... but can same `company_id` can have only null barcodes... so how to do this in MySQL?

any help would be appreciated .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [Composite Unique constraint](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_barcode_company_idx UNIQUE (company_id, barcode);
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a0240/1)

**Details:**

- **MySQL** allows multiple `NULL` values in a column with a unique constraint.
- So, basically you can have multiple rows containing `(1, null)`, where `1` is for `company_id` and `null` for `barcode`

Comment: but this doesnt allow same company_id having null barcodes

Comment: i made it like this "ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_COMAPNY_BARCODE UNIQUE (COMPANY_ID, BARCODE);" but it doesnt allow null barcodes for same comapny_id

Comment: @firstNamelastName It allows on my local MySQL instance. Please share your complete `CREATE TABLE` statement

Comment: ALTER TABLE 'table'
ADD COLUMN `BARCODE` VARCHAR(100),
ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_COMAPNY_BARCODE UNIQUE (COMPANY_ID, BARCODE);

Comment: @firstNamelastName What is your mysql version ?

Comment: 8.0.11 .. this is the version

Comment: @firstNamelastName please check this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a0240/1   I have created two rows with company id and barcode as (1, null).

Comment: the link you provided doesnt open

Answer (score 0):

You can add composite unique key as :

```
ALTER TABLE sometable_name ADD UNIQUE INDEX `unq_indx` (`company_id`,`barcode`);
```

Which allow multiple null values in barcode column for same company name.